# How to retrieve more than 100 artifact versions using method from ADO API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve the latest 3 versions from a specific branch. The process I'm following right now is getting an object that contains the artifact versions of a pipeline, then filtering per artifact and then per version. Still, each artifact only retrieves the latest 100 versions and the version linked to the branch that I'm looking for is not between those 100, I need at least 200 results.

using

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=7.1-preview.1

const artifactversions = await this.releaseApiObject.getArtifactVersions(projectId,definitionId);
```

Is it possible to modify the filter criteria to include a larger range of versions, or to use a different API method that allows me to retrieve more versions at once? Is there a way to retrieve the versions in batches of 100, and then combine the results to get the full list of versions?

The retrieved object looks like this:

```
{
    "artifactVersions": [
        {
            "sourceId": "123123123123",
            "alias": "_Netw---------", 
            "versions": [
                {
                    "id": "123123123",
                    "name": "3.123123123.3168",
                    "definitionId": "123123",
                    "definitionName": "Net123123",
                    "sourceBranch": "refs/master", //I want to filter versions that match a name
                                                   branch criteria
                    "sourceVersion": "1231231231",
                    "sourceRepositoryId": "123123",
                    "sourceRepositoryType": "blabla"
                },
                {
                    "id": "123123123",
                    "name": "3.123123123.3168",
                    "definitionId": "123123",
                    "definitionName": "Net123123",
                    "sourceBranch": "refs/master",
                    "sourceVersion": "1231231231",
                    "sourceRepositoryId": "123123",
                    "sourceRepositoryType": "blabla"
                },
              //other 98 objects like those
              ....}]}];
```

Comment: Hi Karla, I tested the API you shared, but it didn't return the versions of artifacts. Can you confirm if this [Artifacts - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#artifact)   is the rest api you are using? If it is not, please share the API link. Thanks!